# Wingdings Font Not Shown in Tkinter on Macbook

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, fonts

Whenever I run the following snippet (on MacOs 10.13.1 using Python 3.6.1):

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()

open_file = tkinter.Button(window, text="1", font=("Wingdings", 12))
open_file.pack()
```

Instead of showing the following glyph:

[image: What should show up]

The program shows this:

[image: What actually shows]

Is there a way in which I can fix this so that the `Wingdings` font displays correctly?

(Note: The font shows up fine on Windows 10)

Comment: Try using Character viewer

Comment: Having the same issue

Comment: are you certain the "Wingdings" font is installed on your machine? Your code works fine on my mac. After creating a root window, add this line to print out the fonts tkinter knows about: `import tkinter.font; print(tkinter.font.families())`

Comment: Sorry, only checked `StackOverflow` this morning. The tuple printed by `print(tkinter.font.families())` does include `Wingdings`

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem on my mac. When I create a button just like you, it has a folder image on it.